# Airflow dag file is in place but it's not showing up when I do airflow dags list

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I placed a dag file in the dags folder based on a tutorial with slight modifications, but it doesn't show up in the GUI or when run airflow dags list.

Comment: Make sure you didn't forget to set the `dag_id` or that you don't have the same `dag_id` for multiple different dag files.

Answer (score 6):

Answering my own question: Check the python file for Exceptions by running it directly. It turns out one exception in the dag's python script due to a missing import made the dag not show up in the list. I note this just in case another new user comes across this. To me the moral of the story is that dag files should often be checked by running with python directly when they are modified because there won't be an obvious error showing up otherwise; they may just disappear from the list.

Comment: Yep! I would check the DagFileProcessor logs to see why the file is not being parsed successfully by Airflow. The logs will be under `$AIRFLOW_HOME/logs/scheduler/latest/<path_to_dag_file>.log`.

Comment: And you can see errors in the UI of Airflow as a message displayed to the user. Also in Airflow 2 there is the REST API that you can check for the errors: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/get_import_errors

Answer (score 1):

I know you already answered yourself, but I can't comment and wanted to share a similar case.

A python file can be valid executable python, in the right place, with the correct permissions, and getting detected by Airflow... but it still won't show up **unless a valid DAG object has been instantiated** (and if not, no errors will be logged).

You also have to instantiate an object, not just call the function - in my case the DAG finally started appearing when I changed it like this...

```
from airflow.decorators import dag

@dag(...)
def the_dag()
    ...

the_dag() # <-- doesn't work

_ = the_dag() # <-- works
```